# Is it possible to evaluate the summation $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)}{n^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, totient-function

$$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)}{n^a},\quad\text{where $\phi$ is the Euler-phi/totient function and $a\geq1$}$$

Can this even be evaluated? It clearly converges for all $a>2$, since the maximum value of the totient function for any $n$ is $n-1$ and $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{n^a}$ converges if $a>2$.

I honestly have no idea where to begin on this one.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)}{n^a}=\frac{\zeta(a-1)}{\zeta(a)}$$, hence the series with $a=2$ diverges.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Um, doesn't $\frac{\zeta(a-1)}{\zeta(a)}$ converge for real $a>2$? Also do know if there's a specific reference for this identity somewhere?

Comment: @KemonoChen  the OP has asked for a reference, but neglected to put an at sign and your name

Comment: I saw this result in Chapter 3 Exercise 6 and 8 of the book "Introduction to Analytic Number theory" by Tom M. Apostol.

Comment: It follows from $n = \sum_{d | n} \phi(d) $

Comment: The RHS is finite for $a>2$, but the limit as $a\to 2^+$ is $+\infty$.

Comment: @KemonoChen Thanks for the help, I can't accept until you post the answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Kemono Chen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/521015/kemono-chen): This series is discussed in Chapter 3 of Tom M. Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*. Excercises 6 and 8 provide the result

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)}{n^a}=\frac{\zeta(a-1)}{\zeta(a)}$$

With the implication that the series diverges for $a=2$

From [Slade](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33433/slade): While the sum is finite for $a>2$, the limit as $a\to2^+$ is $+\infty$.