# Are the Series Convergent?Why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analysis

(1)Let $p_n$ be the nth prime number,and $P=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_{n}}$;
(2)Let $\varphi(n)$ be the Euler's totient function,and $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n^{2}}$ .

Comment: Possible duplicate of: $$$$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-converge
$$$$
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044654/is-it-possible-to-evaluate-the-summation-x-sum-n-1-infty-frac-phinn2

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your questions are phrased as isolated problems, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you! I have already solved the question!

Comment: $\lim_{s\to 1}\log \zeta(s)=\infty$ implies (1) diverges which implies (2) diverges